# Cannot resolve symbole view

Tags: android

**[SOLVED]** **The working code:**

**Declare:** `private View view;`

**Code:** `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

**Declare:** `private View view;`

**Code:**
`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);
[All Views inside here];
    return v;`

OR SIMPLY:

**Code:** `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -** **- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

I have problem with the coding which keeps throwing me the error message: "Cannot resolve symbole view". I've tried to clean the build, invalidate cashe/restart the project, but without any effect. The problem still persists. This goes for all the "views" used in the below codes:

```
quizLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) `view`.findViewById(R.id.quizLinearLayoutEasy);
questionNumberTextViewEasy = (TextView) `view`.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextViewEasy);
flagImageView = (ImageView) `view`.findViewById(R.id.flagImageViewEasy);

guessLinearLayouts = new LinearLayout[1];
guessLinearLayouts[0] = (LinearLayout) `view`.findViewById(R.id.row1LinearLayoutEasy);
guessLinearLayouts[1] = (LinearLayout) `view`.findViewById(R.id.row2LinearLayoutEasy);
answerTextView = (TextView) `view`.findViewById(R.id.answerTextViewEasy);
return `view`;
```

.

**Here's my java code showing how these are used:**
.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
...
private LinearLayout quizLinearLayout; // layout that contains the quiz
private TextView questionNumberTextViewEasy; // shows current question #
private ImageView flagImageView; // displays a flag
private LinearLayout[] guessLinearLayouts; // rows of answer Buttons
private TextView answerTextView; // displays correct answer

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        quizCountriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        random = new SecureRandom();
        handler = new Handler();

        // load the shake animation that's used for incorrect answers
        shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.incorrect_shake);
        shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3); // animation repeats 3 times

        // get references to GUI components
        quizLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.quizLinearLayoutEasy);
        questionNumberTextViewEasy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextViewEasy);
        flagImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flagImageViewEasy);

        guessLinearLayouts = new LinearLayout[1];
        guessLinearLayouts[0] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row1LinearLayoutEasy);
        guessLinearLayouts[1] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row2LinearLayoutEasy);
        answerTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.answerTextViewEasy);

        // configure listeners for the guess Buttons
        for (LinearLayout row : guessLinearLayouts) {
            for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {
                Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                button.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
            }//for-loop int column ends here
        }//for-loop LinearLayout row ends here

        // set questionNumberTextViewEasy's text
        questionNumberTextViewEasy.setText(
                getString(R.string.question, 1, FLAGS_IN_QUIZ));
        return view; // return the fragment's view for display

    }//onCreateView ends here
```

.

**my XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/quizLinearLayoutEasy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.android.testingflagquiz.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionNumberTextViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flagImageViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guessCountryTextViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/guess_country"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4c4c4c" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row3LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton1Easy"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton2Easy"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row4LinearLayoutEasy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton3Easy"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answerButton4Easy"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerTextViewEasy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="@dimen/answer_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

.

**My AndroidManifest.xml (if of any use)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.testingflagquiz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your class extending to fragment or Activity ?

Comment: It extends to Fragment: `public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {`

Comment: Ok,check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Declare view on top like

```
private View view;
```

then Replace this line

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

By

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Final Code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        quizCountriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        random = new SecureRandom();
        handler = new Handler();

        // load the shake animation that's used for incorrect answers
        shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.incorrect_shake);
        shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3); // animation repeats 3 times

        // get references to GUI components
        quizLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.quizLinearLayoutEasy);
        questionNumberTextViewEasy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextViewEasy);
        flagImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flagImageViewEasy);

        guessLinearLayouts = new LinearLayout[1];
        guessLinearLayouts[0] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row1LinearLayoutEasy);
        guessLinearLayouts[1] = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row2LinearLayoutEasy);
        answerTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.answerTextViewEasy);

        // configure listeners for the guess Buttons
        for (LinearLayout row : guessLinearLayouts) {
            for (int column = 0; column < row.getChildCount(); column++) {
                Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(column);
                button.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
            }//for-loop int column ends here
        }//for-loop LinearLayout row ends here

        // set questionNumberTextViewEasy's text
        questionNumberTextViewEasy.setText(
                getString(R.string.question, 1, FLAGS_IN_QUIZ));
        return view; // return the fragment's view for display

    }//onCreateView ends here
```

Comment: Still throws red error on all the views, including the view in the line you suggested.

Comment: @FisnikB. See my updated answer please. Declare view variable on top, it will resolve your error.

Comment: Works mate. It actually did work with the suggestions from John Joe too, just that I needed to declare it as well with: `private View view;` Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @FisnikB. Please Upvote & accept answer if it is helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);
    questionNumberTextViewEasy = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextViewEasy);
    return v;
 }
```

Move everything inside the `onCreateView`

Comment: The " are only used to point out the views. If you look at my java-file I don't have them there. So that's not where my problem reside.

Comment: Still throws me an error on the views. Also it included error on the "ParentViewGroup", which I believe you just edited with "container". Still throws me red error on the view with the container included.

Comment: I declare `View v`. You should change my `v` to `view`. It will work after this.

Comment: Just needed to be declared on top. That solved the trick. Dharmbir Singh: posted another solution below as well that works equally good.

Comment: It depends. You can declare on top , as global or can declare inside `@Override`, like mine. Both worked.

Comment: Why can't I mark both of your answers. Both worked well, damnit :P.

Comment: @FisnikB. You can mark only one answer, if you want both then you can upvote. That's the solution.

Comment: Yeah I see. Besides, I think the return part was a mistake that I must have gotten from another line of code and was left there for a reason. When I re-checked the original code that I stripped down, it was only View view and not return -.-'.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh or John Joe: you have time for another problem? I don't have any coding for this one, but I'm in real need of help! I'm working on a project for my course, it's a Flag Quiz. I just don't know how to code it so that I can load Images (country flags) from my assets folder and display it on a ImageView? Further, by pressing 1 of 4 buttons the player will guess the flag.

Comment: post what have you tried by asking a new question. We're here to help

Comment: @JohnJoe: this code above you guys just solved for me, this is actually a part of a working code. However, it is a bit too advanced and have features I won't need. So I tried to strip it down to the parts that I need in hope to get it to work the same way. But I'm stuck -.-'. I was hoping the app would open after your guys help, but it won't :/. Further, I assume it's a bit too much work and complicated to just throw the code out there without you guys knowing how the original looked like. That's why I thought it's probably better to just start from scratch.

Comment: what are the problem now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138737/discussion-between-fisnik-b-and-john-joe).

Comment: @DharmbirSingh: here's the link mate: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t3kbgsrawtoam67/AAAXKR0uWQp1Lo_LuiZ2y8yMa?dl=0 (TestKing is the file I've been working on. FlagQuiz is the original file I used to modify mine). Appreciate any help!